# Issue creating unlocked package version with translations (not available for deploy for this organization)

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, translation, unlocked-package

I'm trying to create an unlocked package in API v47 that contains translations ([which I think should be supported in unlocked packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47)) but I'm getting the following error:

> Error  force-app/main/default/translations/es.translation-meta.xml 
>   Not available for deploy for this organization

I'm trying to pack against a DevHub and so far this is what I've tried to not avail:

- Make sure translations are enabled in the ORG.
- Make sure communities are enabled in the ORG.
- Make sure the API version in the project matches the ORG API version.

It doesn't look like it's a metadata issue because I'm able to deploy the project just fine doing a standard force:push, it's only happening specifically when I try to package.
In any case, here's what the translation file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customLabels>
        <label>Acerca de</label>
        <name>AboutUs</name>
    </customLabels>
</Translations>
```